# Lecture Notes in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, big-list, book-recommendation

I understand that this question was partially addressed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302023/best-sets-of-lecture-notes-and-articles) but I would like to have a question dedicated to just real analysis. I am looking for both elementary real analysis (advanced calculus type material ) and higher level material. It would also be nice if people can attest to the quality of the material.

edit:
Online notes preferred but not necessarily exclusively.

So far I have been using these:

Terence Tao's
http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/245a.1.10f/

Some Stanford ones
http://math.stanford.edu/~maksimm/notes/

Comment: Is this for online-notes only?

Comment: No can be physical notes but they would need to be accessible by the public, i.e. can be purchased or the owner is willing to share. So if you're thinking like your personal set of notes from class then no!

Comment: @grayQuant Take a look at: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/2400full.pdf

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the most beautiful and clearly explained books on mathematics that I have read:

[Understanding Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387950605) by Stephen Abbot