# Open source lecture notes and textbooks

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education, big-list, book-recommendation

This question is inspired by the popular "[Best Sets of Lecture Notes and Articles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302023/best-sets-of-lecture-notes-and-articles)".

Indeed, I would like to collect a "big-list" of *open source* (that is, with $\LaTeX$ code available) high-quality (according to strictly mathematical and pedagogical standard) lecture notes or textbooks on as many mathematical topics as possible.

---

Note that here the focus is only on *open source* lecture notes or books (which could help students to create their own notes for self-study more easily by modifying existing works).

---

Among the many other topics that I would like the material to cover, in particular I am currently interested in:

- calculus;
- real analysis;
- complex and functional analysis;
- abstract algebra;
- linear algebra;
- number theory;
- general physics;
- mathematical physics (mainly classical mechanics);
- probability;
- geometry;
- etc.

---

**Update:** I am thankful for the answers provided so far, and I encourage to share here more examples of good opensource material in the areas which have not been covered.

Comment: Modifying for personal use *without redistribution* does not require open source license.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla but without the source-code you have to write and typeset everything on your own. Having some other good work as a basis makes everything easier.

Comment: OK, I understandt your requirement.

Comment: By with $\LaTeX$ code, does that mean you want the .tex file too? I haven't check the answered links, but I don't think many people will give you their .tex file. I have a substantial amount of notes typed in PDEs, Classical Mech, Fourier Series and Integral Transform, ... but I would never give someone my .tex file. For one they could edit the file saying they authored it, not cool.

Comment: @dustin I know that there are many professors willing to share their knowledge who give out editable files to help students (1) to gain an understanding of some subjects freely; (2) to develop their own material. What I'm searching for are indeed .tex file of open source textbooks and notes which I can edit and use for self-study purposes.

Comment: Have you found any .tex files in those links though? I checked a few and haven't seen any.

Comment: @dustin So far, I've checked some of the links provided by Martin and Mark, and they have indeed the source-codes.

Comment: I feel the .tex wont be easy to come by for a notes or book level document. If you get one or two, that would be good.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The course [Measure Theory](http://www.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt.htm) by D.H.Fremlin includes TeX source.

[Topology Course](http://at.yorku.ca/i/a/a/b/23.htm) by Aisling McCluskey and Brian McMaster in HTML.

Diverse [lecture notes](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~houghton/231/07-08/notes.php) by Conor Houghton.

[Cryptography homework](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr10/cos433/) by Boaz Barak.

[Digital Image Processing](http://eeweb.poly.edu/~onur/lectures/lectures.html).

[Abstract Algebra handouts and Number Theory lecture notes](http://math.bard.edu/belk/math332s09/).

Answer (score 10):

Many of the courses in MIT's OCW have such notes: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/find-by-department/

Answer (score 9):

Here are a few I've found over the years.  I've included some brief comments on the first four, which I've personally used in my classes.

- [Stitz and Zeager Precalculus materials](http://www.stitz-zeager.com/)
  Outstanding.  Includes a lot of ancillaries like answers and youtube videos.
  CCL
- [Mooculus](https://mooculus.osu.edu/)
  Very, very good calculus MOOC offered at Ohio State University.  Text is freely available by itself.  One limitation - it covers only single variable.
  CCL
- [Whitman Calclus](http://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/multivariable/) by David Guichard
  Very good and complete Calculus text.
  CCL
- [APEX Calculus](http://www.apexcalculus.com/)
  The most recent open text that I've used for Calculus. Almost as good as Mooculus and almost as complete as Guichard.
  CCL
- [A First Course in Complex Analysis](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/papers/complex.analysis.html) Beck, Marchesi, and Pixton
  Very good - Freely available but not open.
- [Linear Algebra](https://hefferon.net/linearalgebra/) by Jim Hefferon
  This book won the [2020 Daniel Solow Author's Award](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Awards/Solow_2020_Hefferon.pdf) from the Mathematical Association of America.
  GFDL or CC BY-SA
- [A First Course in Linear Algebra](http://linear.ups.edu/)
  GFDL
- [Abstract Algebra](http://abstract.ups.edu/) by Tom Judson
  GFDL
- [Basic Analysis - An Introduction to Real Analysis](http://www.jirka.org/ra/) by Jiri Lebl
  CCL

Answer (score 8):

The Stacks Project and the CRing project are good for learning algebraic geometry and commutative algebra, respectively:

- Stacks Project: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/
- CRing Project: http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~amathew/cr.html

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check this site for over 46.000 free ebooks. Copyrights of the books contained in this site are expired so you can freely download books. You can download the books in PDF, EPUB or LATEX.

main site : https://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Main_Page

math bookshelf : https://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Mathematics_%28Bookshelf%29

Comment: At least this covers not only the technical aspect of being copyable but also the license. That being said, while one can find a couple of interesting and famous original texts, other stuff is not really up to date (regarding content, methods, or even notation)

Answer (score 2):

[Rob Beezer's "A First Course in Linear Algebra"](http://linear.ups.edu/) represents the future of OER textbooks for math, imho. His [MathBook XML](http://mathbook.pugetsound.edu/) production flow allows a single source input (written in xml) to output in multiple formats (right now pdf-via-LaTeX and html, but the future could include more). To compete with commercial textbooks, both a quality book and a quality web-accessible e-book are necessary. (As well as a third leg: a quality online homework platform like WeBWorK.)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some lecture notes for Operations Research that I have found on professor’s sites (that are now defunct due to the passage of time and losing domain names) that I’ve been using as a supplement to my own self-studying and coursework:

[Operations Research - Deterministic Models](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Estacho/public/IEOR4004-notes1.pdf) lecture notes by Juraj Stacho of Columbia University New York

[Operations Research](https://web.itu.edu.tr/topcuil/ya/OR.pdf) lecture notes by [Dr. Y Īlker Topcu](https://web.archive.org/web/20190218002650/http://www.ilkertopcu.info/)