# Good electronic references or good textbooks (pdf) in some topics

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

Well now I am interested in good books that I can find in the web of Probability (from basic to more difficult),abstract algebra,calculus 4 or complex calculus. All of them with exercise and the solutions please for practice.

Can you help me please with this?, thanks in advance :).

Comment: What is calculus $4$ exactly (multivariable?, analysis on manifolds?, what's the textbook you're assigned?) and what's wrong with your campus's library?

Comment: well is closed now hahahahah, but calculus 4 is complex calculus or calculus in complex variable :)

Comment: I generally can't find any good web references for upper division topics, but I can give you some textbook references if you like.

Comment: yes please :) I appreciated it  :)

Comment: I have not used any of these books, but [here's](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/papers/complex.pdf) an open source book on complex analysis and [here](http://math.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_free_mathematics_books) are several freely available books on several topics including probability theory and abstract algebra.  And [Mark's answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1027936/open-source-lecture-notes-and-textbooks?rq=1) includes a book on complex analysis and one on abstract algebra.

Comment: Thanks in advance really :) I'll check it

Answer (score 3):

In terms of .pdf suggestions, Robert Ash has a nice Probability text, "Basic Probability Theory," and you can find a .pdf version of Bertsekas/Tsitsiklis "Introduction to Probability," used at MIT in a nice course in the electrical engineering department. Ash also has an introductory graduate text in Algebra and a text in complex variables (neither of which I've perused personally), available on his [webpage](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/).