# Recent sets of notes/newly available online books on category theory?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, self-learning, online-resources

Background: I have had for some time a [Category Theory webpage (here)](http://www.logicmatters.net/categories/) which lists about 20 substantial sets of lecture notes on category theory, and another 16 more or less well-known books that have officially been made freely available online. This page is very steadily visited thousands of times a month, so must be being found useful. So I feel I should now trye to maintain it as a contribution to the community.

I'm not aiming to be completist but I do want to cover the good stuff that's available! I have just added a few more links and checked that existing links are still correct. But I'm not a real category theorist myself, so all help/advice for keeping it updated is gratefully received.  So now the query to anyone teaching/working on category theory or who has recently done a course:

> Any recommendations of further substantial sets of lecture notes on category theory at introductory/intermediate level, in particular *recent*  ones?
>
> And any pointers to further books previously only available in dead tree form that have recently been made *officially* available online for free download?

(By 'recent', say sometime in the last two or three years.)

Comment: I assume you have seen these questions already: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370/good-books-and-lecture-notes-about-category-theory?rq=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302023/best-sets-of-lecture-notes-and-articles?rq=1 They are not exactly duplicates but maybe there are a few links there that do no appear on your page.

Comment: Yes of course. But that was some years ago -- hence my question about *recent* additions -- particularly meaning last two/three years, to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that recent, but drafts of the book "Algebraic Theories: A Categorical Introduction to General Algebra" by Adamek, Rosicky and Vitale are available on [Adamek's](https://www.tu-braunschweig.de/iti/mitarbeiter/adamek/books) and [Vitale's](https://perso.uclouvain.be/enrico.vitale/research.html) webpages (Vitale's version is more recent, and slightly longer). It is published by Cambridge University Press, and I think they allow authors to put their drafts online (similarly to Emily Riehl's "Category Theory in Context" that you put on your page).